# TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'en'

Tags: node.js, soap

I'm running a Node.js service that uses [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap) to convert a soap response from another service to JSON which then gets returned to the caller. It also works in the other directions, turning JSON into Soap and delivering it to the service.

But I'm getting the following error when calling a couple of services:

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'en'
at C:\...\soap.js:47:11
at C:\...\node_modules\soap\lib\client.js:84:13
at C:\...\node_modules\soap\lib\client.js:150:24
at Request._callback (C:\...\node_modules\soap\lib\http.js:48:13)
at Request.self.callback (C:\...\node_modules\soap\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\soap\node_modules\request\index.js:876:14)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\soap\node_modules\request\index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

I've been unable to find anyone posting the same error, nor finding out what this could be.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `C:\...\soap.js:47:11` and fix the line that calls `.en` instead of `.on`. It's just a typo I think.

Comment: You know, your right. I totally read that line as a .on and started to look at the libraries I am using instead.